# Recursive component works only outside that component

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have problem that my recursive component isnt nesting itself

I'm looping through `Indexes` of `Childs` of `Element` and displaying them after mapping them to desired objects - that part works correctly because `root` is inserted to `Recusrive` component from other component,
but when I try to use `Recursive` component inside `Recusrive` component then it doesn't work and there's 0 errors on console

but there's something like that in DOM:

```
<div>
    <!--function(t,n,r,i){return et(e,t,n,r,i,!0)}-->
</div>
<div>
    <!--function(t,n,r,i){return et(e,t,n,r,i,!0)}-->
</div>
```

---

```
<template>
   <div>
       {{element.Id}}
        <div v-for="child in element.Childs.map(x => document[x])">
            Child: [{{child}}] <-- shows fine
            <Recursive :element="child"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script src="./recursive.ts"></script>
```

---

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

@Component({
    props: ['element'],

    computed: {
        ...mapState(['document']),
    },

    components: {
        Recursive: require('./recursive.vue.html')
    }
})
export default class RecursiveComponent extends Vue {
}
```

Anybody has an idea what can be wrong?

Comment: recursive components need a name - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Recursive-Components

Comment: @Estradiaz Please write it as an answer, so I'll be able to accept! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive Components need a `name` property.

[Further readings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Recursive-Components)

> Components can recursively invoke themselves in their own template. However, they can only do so with the name option:
>
> `name: 'unique-name-of-my-component'`